# clickhouse round error in new version 18.10.3

Tags: clickhouse

centos7-231 :)  select round(123.454, 2), **round(123.445, 2)**;

SELECT 
    round(123.454, 2), 
    round(123.445, 2)

┌─round(123.454, 2)─┬─round(123.445, 2)─┐
│            123.45 │            **123.44** │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.

centos7-231 :) select version();

SELECT version()

┌─version()─┐
│ 18.10.3   │
└───────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.005 sec.

round(123.445, 2)  should get 123.45,why clickhouse get 123.44?  somebody help!

In the old version clickhouse:
Connected to ClickHouse server version 1.1.54318.

:)              select round(123.455, 2), **round(123.445, 2)**;

SELECT 
    round(123.455, 2), 
    round(123.445, 2)

┌─round(123.455, 2)─┬─round(123.445, 2)─┐
│            123.46 │            **123.45** │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┘

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse uses [Banker's Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) which rounds half to even.